# Golang unmarshal change structure index to defined value

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

See code below:

Print out v.Src[0] and v.Src[1] brings up "MySource" and "MySource2".

But comparing the XML, the entries [0] and [1] do not follow the id's set in `<id>x</id>`

How can I achieve that the decoder is using the `<id>x</id>` as index?

Target: v.Src[1] prints "MySource"

Here is my working code

package main

```
import (

    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

    type Flow struct {
        Id   string `xml:"id"`
        Name string `xml:"name"`
    }
    type Src struct {
        Id    string `xml:"id"`
        Name  string `xml:"name"`
        Flows []Flow `xml:"flows>flow"`
    }
    type Result struct {
        Src   []Src  `xml:"bar>sources>source"`


    }

func main() {
    data := `
    <foo>
        <bar>
            <sources>
                <source>
                  <id>1</id>
                    <name>MySource</name>

                    <flows>
                      <flow>
                        <id>1</id>
                        <name>MySource 1L</name>
                      </flow>
                      <flow>
                        <id>2</id>
                        <name>MySource 1R</name>
                      </flow>
                    </flows>   
                </source>
                <source>
                  <id>2</id>
                    <name>MySource2</name>

                    <flows>
                      <flow>
                        <id>1</id>
                        <name>MySource2 2L</name>
                      </flow>
                      <flow>
                        <id>2</id>
                        <name>MySource2 2R</name>
                      </flow>
                    </flows>   
                </source>
            </sources>
        </bar>
    </foo>`

    v := Result{}

    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &v)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("%#v", v)
    fmt.Printf("%#v", v.Src[0].Name) //Prints: "MySource"
    fmt.Printf("%#v", v.Src[1].Name) //Prints: "MySource2"
}
```

Many thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0):

As `v.Src` is a slice with `Src` its indices reveal only order of elements but not their inner fields. How to solve a task:

1. Make special map with pointers to elements

   ```
   srcs := make(map[int64]*Src)

   for index, src := range v.Src {
       id, _ := strconv.ParseInt(src.Id, 10, 64)
       srcs[id] = &(v.Src[index])
   }

   fmt.Printf("Srcs: %v\n", srcs)
   fmt.Printf("%#v\n", srcs[1].Name) //Prints: "MySource"
   fmt.Printf("%#v\n", srcs[2].Name) //Prints: "MySource2"
   ```

   https://play.golang.org/p/6y3uW2jV13
2. Use XPath to access elements with specific properties and then select like `//source[./id=1]/name`